# Not getting callback for onReceivedClientCertRequest in Webview

Tags: android, ssl, webview, ssl-certificate, webclient

I need to do Public key /Certificate pinning for Webview. I see there is an api has been introduced in API21
As per Android documentation,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedClientCertRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.ClientCertRequest)

`onReceivedClientCertRequest()` is added in api 21, but I am not getting callback when I load any url. Could anyone please help????

```
@Override
public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, final ClientCertRequest request) {
            Log.e("ClientCertRequest", "===> certificate required!");

            KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(WebViewActivity.this, new KeyChainAliasCallback(){
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                @Override
                public void alias(String alias) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "===>Key alias is: " + alias);
                    try {
                        PrivateKey changPrivateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(WebViewActivity.this, alias);
                        X509Certificate[] certificates = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(WebViewActivity.this, alias);
                        Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "===>Getting Private Key Success!" );
                        request.proceed(changPrivateKey, certificates);
                    } catch (KeyChainException e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), Util.printException(e));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), Util.printException(e));
                    }
                }
            },new String[]{"RSA"}, null, null, -1, null);
            super.onReceivedClientCertRequest(view,request);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client Certificate Authentication can fail in a number of ways in Android:

- Your WebViewClient might not be wired properly: make sure you get other notifications from the WebView such as `WebViewClient.onPageStarted()`
- Make sure you're actually using SSL and a https URL
- SSL might fail before you even get to the client certificate check. This is typical for self signed server certificates. You can work around this problem by calling `handler.proceed()` in `WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error)`
- SSL client certificate authentication might not be turned on on the server side. When using Apache, set something like `SSLVerifyClient require` along with the required parameters `SSLVerifyDepth` and `SSLCACertificateFile` in the config
- Use a valid CA certificate (created by you or a third party) on the server and a client certificate that was signed by this CA certificate
- Make sure the client certificate is installed on the Android device. You typically copy the client certificate to the device's storage as a PKCS 12 file (pfx file extension)